# Android - Supporting multiple screens canvas issue

Tags: android, xml, layout, canvas, screen

I did a test game using this tutorial http://www.kilobolt.com/day-6-the-android-game-framework-part-ii.html and now I want to do a real game for publishing on the play store.

I want my game to support different screen sizes. So after reading a lot I now know that I have to specify different layouts for different screen sizes. But I don't know what to do about some code from the tutorial.

It basically has something like this:

```
int frameBufferWidth = 800;
int frameBufferHeight = 480;
Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth, frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);
```

which is then used to create the Canvas:

```
this.canvas = new Canvas(frameBuffer);
```

- How do I adapt that into the layouts?
- Are those sizes in pixels?
- Should I pass them to dp values?
- Should I specify those width and height values on the xml layouts?

I think the correct answer would be to pass them to dp on the code, but even so, I don't really know how to do it.

I asked the same question on the tutorial website but haven't got any response yet, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I was going to suggest using dp if you were specifying sizes in xml, and px if you were doing it dynamically, but that is bad advice. I know you hate to hear this, but it really all depends on what you are trying to do.

If you are coding a statusbar, you always want it the same size no matter what screen size - for that, use px. I don't see how you can do this with dp.

On the other hand, say you have an image you want to be exactly half the screen - you have a few options. If you are doing it in code, you can use either - speed-wise it's insignificant. If you are doing it in xml, you can either set it to 80dp directly, or (and this is what I do), just use linearlayouts with weights.

To be honest, I never use dp, but I completely see the convenience of it in some cases. I use pixels and weighted layouts for everything, and I am able to do everything that way. Take it for what it's worth, but I feel it is more exact, can get better resolution, expands better to different screen sizes, and more intuitive. But if you prefer using dp, do that. It's really whatever you feel more comfortable with. Both ways are completely acceptable, and whoever tells you one is better than the other for everything,  just stop listening.

---

In your activity, try using:

```
Point size = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
int frameBufferWidth = size.x;
int frameBufferHeight = size.y;
```

However, that's only for api>13. For earlier versions, use:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int frameBufferHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
int frameBufferWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
```

NOTE: These functions get size in pixels. to convert between px and dp, you can do this:

```
float factor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int realwidth = (int) Math.round(width/factor); <--to convert px to dp
//int realwidth = (int) Math.round(width*factor); <--to convert dp to px
```

Comment: Ok, so getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size) gets the device screen size on px or dp?

Comment: getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size) returns pixels (px)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, those methods are actually helpful. But my main question remains. What should I do? Do you think It's better to pass those values to dp?

Comment: Thanks. Well, I'm thinking of doing everything by code, the position and size of the objects in the game, and even the options on the menu. So I guess I'll use dp for everything and see how that works out on different devices. With that in mind, do you think i'll need to use layouts? I read that in games they can be ignored.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. You may need to make a few layouts, but probably nothing extensive. They're really a piece of cake, especially for games which have minimal guis.